# Evaluation $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ [$1\over(a+n)$+$1\over(2a+n)$+$1\over(3a+n)$+......$1\over(na+n)$]

Tags: limits

Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ [$1\over(a+n)$+$1\over(2a+n)$+$1\over(3a+n)$+......$1\over(na+n)$]
where a is a positive number

How to evaluate the above limit?
For ${n\to\infty}$ answer is coming out to be zero.

Comment: You are adding n values which are each >= 1 / ((a + 1)n), so their sum will be at least 1 / (a + 1). Seems unlikely that the limit is zero.

Comment: This might be amongst the most duplicated questions on the site.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $$\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1}{ka+n}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\frac{k}{n}a+1}\dfrac{1}{n}$$ and Riemann sums.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+ka}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{1+\frac kna}$$
Can you recognize a Riemann integral here?